# Need two siblings to expand to height of parent without explicit height of parent set

Tags: html, css

I have a container that can not have an explicit height, it must expand to the height of the children. Both children must be equal height regardless of content, which is set by the taller of the two children.

Here is a fiddle of my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/efrntzwx/74/

I need the blue section to expand to the height of the red container while keeping padding intact.

```
html, body, .container {
  /* height: 100%; */
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1, .child2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child1content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.child2content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child1">
        <div class="child1content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at tellus eget ex semper feugiat. Etiam maximus non est at egestas. Proin fermentum ipsum eget enim iaculis mattis eu non elit. Fusce fringilla neque vel mauris vulputate elementum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque sodales erat augue, a volutpat nunc ultrices quis. Cras feugiat, metus a dapibus condimentum, lorem nulla malesuada enim, et sodales arcu sapien eu sem. Proin vel vulputate magna. Integer rhoncus iaculis justo, eget dignissim massa tempus a. Nullam ut malesuada diam. Vestibulum aliquam ligula eget turpis viverra dignissim. Maecenas elementum nec erat sit amet bibendum. Nulla in hendrerit orci. Duis elit dui, iaculis quis dapibus condimentum, viverra id libero. Suspendisse potenti.

Etiam blandit scelerisque eleifend. Vestibulum non mauris erat. Mauris sed massa sodales, tristique mi ut, suscipit leo. Nam porttitor urna ac nulla malesuada, ac blandit orci bibendum. Aliquam luctus quis ante ac suscipit. Sed sed sapien vestibulum nulla venenatis sodales. Pellentesque ultricies tellus non vehicula ornare. Cras quis aliquet tellus. Mauris nec leo quis metus dignissim laoreet non a nisi. Aenean finibus nunc a augue laoreet, porttitor ullamcorper odio imperdiet. Vivamus pellentesque, leo vitae dignissim varius, elit metus faucibus justo, vel pharetra lectus erat eu lorem. Pellentesque scelerisque tortor elit, at facilisis nisi suscipit at. Nulla facilisi.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child2">
        <div class="child2content">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try to add this ``.child1, .child2{height:auto;}``

Answer (score 0):

I added `flex-1` property for two child.  In this way, the two elements will have the same width and height in each case. What I have changed and added is the specification in the comment lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .child1,
    .child2 {
      padding: 50px 100px;
      /* if you want to always same height and width in the container  remove this*/
    }
    
    .child1 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      flex: 1;
      /*added*/
    }
    
    .child2 {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      flex: 1;
      /*added*/
    }
    
    .child1content {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .child2content {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
      <div class="child1content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at tellus eget ex semper feugiat. Etiam maximus non est at egestas. Proin fermentum ipsum eget enim iaculis mattis eu non elit. Fusce fringilla neque vel mauris vulputate elementum. Vestibulum
        ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque sodales erat augue, a volutpat nunc ultrices quis. Cras feugiat, metus a dapibus condimentum, lorem nulla malesuada enim, et sodales arcu sapien eu sem.
        Proin vel vulputate magna. Integer rhoncus iaculis justo, eget dignissim massa tempus a. Nullam ut malesuada diam. Vestibulum aliquam ligula eget turpis viverra dignissim. Maecenas elementum nec erat sit amet bibendum. Nulla in hendrerit orci.
        Duis elit dui, iaculis quis dapibus condimentum, viverra id libero. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam blandit scelerisque eleifend. Vestibulum non mauris erat. Mauris sed massa sodales, tristique mi ut, suscipit leo. Nam porttitor urna ac nulla malesuada,
        ac blandit orci bibendum. Aliquam luctus quis ante ac suscipit. Sed sed sapien vestibulum nulla venenatis sodales. Pellentesque ultricies tellus non vehicula ornare. Cras quis aliquet tellus. Mauris nec leo quis metus dignissim laoreet non a nisi.
        Aenean finibus nunc a augue laoreet, porttitor ullamcorper odio imperdiet. Vivamus pellentesque, leo vitae dignissim varius, elit metus faucibus justo, vel pharetra lectus erat eu lorem. Pellentesque scelerisque tortor elit, at facilisis nisi
        suscipit at. Nulla facilisi.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <div class="child2content">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```